# Unhandled exception when saving a site as a template

Tags: site-template

I've been saving my site as a template successfully for a while, but after adding a new dialog to my 'Action Items' list in SharePoint Designer, I am no longer able to export my site.

The original error said the problem was with my Action Items list, however when I deleted that it just changed the message to the next list alphabetically.  There is nothing in the Logs about this failure.

```
Error exporting the list named "Announcements" at the URL: Lists/Announcements

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Error exporting the list named "Announcements" at the URL: Lists/Announcements

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SPException: Error exporting the list named "Announcements" at the URL: Lists/Announcements]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportLists() +27187216
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GenerateSolutionFiles() +511
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebAsSolution() +27148930
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb web, String solutionFileName, String title, String description, ExportMode exportMode, Boolean includeContent, String workflowTemplateName, String destinationListUrl) +1826
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb web, String solutionFileName, String title, String description, ExportMode exportMode, Boolean includeContent) +44
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.SaveAsTemplatePage.BtnSaveAsTemplate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +331
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

I found this suggestion about [deactivating content types](http://www.serious-sharepoint.com/?p=81) but it made no difference.  There is also no correlation Id given, and I get the same error when I try to export it from powershell.  Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Are you using a Custom Field, because a site were a custom field is used can not be saved as a template

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this post for similar issues like yours - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/676d0475-138d-4874-bb3f-8b8c840752fc

The post specifies about error even when creating a site with the saved site template.

Since your site had no issues previously, I would also recommend to restore a backup of the site from the database if possible. This would bring back the site to the previous working condition and you would be able to save as site template again.

Comment: In the thread you linked he is able to save a template but cannot create a site from it.  My problem is that I cannot even save a template.  This user is also getting a file not found error in the logs, while in my case there are no logs and I get an 'unhandled exception' while sharepoint exports a list.